# Edge Bookmarks write new bookmarks folder always goes to last position

Tags: c#, microsoft-edge, bookmarks

I have created a simple executable with C# to serialize and deserialize the JSON for the Edge bookmarks.
I am forcing the child to append to the first position, but when Edge is open it quickly rewrites the JSON and moves the folder to the last position.

```
listChildToAddEdge.Insert(1, currentChildToChange);
```

How can I force the position to this folder?

Comment: It looks like no matter where you would like to put the newly added child, Edge just appends it unless you sort it in the browser instead of arranging it via code. I'm afraid you have to drag and drop them inside the browser to make a rearrangement permanently. Also, you can make a suggestion of arranging the order via code to the Microsoft Edge Team. Press **Alt+Shift+I** in Edge to send a feedback to them.

Answer (score 0):

The problem, in this case, is the account logged in the browser.
When an account is logged on the browser, the bookmarks in the cloud always overwrite the position of the bookmarks created.